# How to measure the a time-span in seconds using System.currentTimeMillis()?

Tags: java, milliseconds

How to convert `System.currentTimeMillis();` to seconds?

```
long start6=System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(counter.countPrimes(100000000)+" for "+start6);
```

The console shows me `5761455 for 1307816001290`.
I can't read how many seconds that is.

Any help?

Comment: `long s = System.currentTimeMilis() / 1000L`

Comment: Try Instant will more clearly:                                                                       long s = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
counter.countPrimes(1000000);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println("Took : " + ((end - start) / 1000));
```

**UPDATE**

An even more accurate solution would be:

```
final long start = System.nanoTime();
counter.countPrimes(1000000);
final long end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Took: " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
System.out.println("Took: " + (end - start)/ 1000000000 + " seconds");
```

Comment: The time in nanoseconds needs to be divided by 10^9 (1000000000) to display as seconds. Can't edit the answer as I only have to insert 3 characters instead of the 6 required. :]

Comment: Sorry, wanted it to be ms instead of s. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Why would someone want to use `nanoTime()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()` when the result is needed in seconds?

Comment: I, uh, didn't consider that. It was still good to learn of `nanoTime`'s existence for me as it would be fairly more useful in scenarios where many large volumes of operations need to be timed or logged.

Comment: @Uooo `currentTimeMillis()` is for "wall time", and `nanoTime()` is high resolution elapsed time. There is a slight difference in them, and their purpose. `nanoTime()` is not affected by local time settings, clock corrections and such, and the difference of a later to earlier call is guaranteed to never be negative (on the same VM, in the same power cycle). There is no such guarantee for `currentTimeMillis()`. Use `currentTimeMillis()` to answer "with current time settings, how much time passed since 1970 jan 1", not "how much more time passed since I last called this function"

Answer (score 102):

## `TimeUnit`

Use the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) built into Java 5 and later.

```
long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMillis);
```

Comment: Wow, havn't heard about the TimeUnit thing before.

Comment: seems like not working for me :O can you please help out?It still give me the result same as `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Haven't heard of this method, nice. But you loose precision when 1500 msecs are converted to 1 sec, not that nice.

Comment: @PeterClause Of course you lose resolution going from fractional seconds to whole seconds. What else would you expect?

Answer (score 16):

like so:

```
(int)(milliseconds / 1000)
```

Answer (score 10):

Java 8 now provides the most concise method to get current Unix Timestamp:

```
Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

Answer (score 9):

From your code it would appear that you are trying to measure how long a computation took (as opposed to trying to figure out what the current time is).

In that case, you need to call `currentTimeMillis` before and after the computation, take the difference, and divide the result by 1000 to convert milliseconds to seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I have written the following code in my last assignment, it may help you:

```
// A method that converts the nano-seconds to Seconds-Minutes-Hours form
private static String formatTime(long nanoSeconds)
{
    int hours, minutes, remainder, totalSecondsNoFraction;
    double totalSeconds, seconds;


    // Calculating hours, minutes and seconds
    totalSeconds = (double) nanoSeconds / 1000000000.0;
    String s = Double.toString(totalSeconds);
    String [] arr = s.split("\\.");
    totalSecondsNoFraction = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    hours = totalSecondsNoFraction / 3600;
    remainder = totalSecondsNoFraction % 3600;
    minutes = remainder / 60;
    seconds = remainder % 60;
    if(arr[1].contains("E")) seconds = Double.parseDouble("." + arr[1]);
    else seconds += Double.parseDouble("." + arr[1]);


    // Formatting the string that conatins hours, minutes and seconds
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(".");
    String sep = "", nextSep = " and ";
    if(seconds > 0)
    {
        result.insert(0, " seconds").insert(0, seconds);
        sep = nextSep;
        nextSep = ", ";
    }
    if(minutes > 0)
    {
        if(minutes > 1) result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " minutes").insert(0, minutes);
        else result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " minute").insert(0, minutes);
        sep = nextSep;
        nextSep = ", ";
    }
    if(hours > 0)
    {
        if(hours > 1) result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " hours").insert(0, hours);
        else result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " hour").insert(0, hours);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Just convert nano-seconds to milli-seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(start6, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

For conversion of milliseconds to seconds, since 1 second = 10³ milliseconds:

```
//here m will be in seconds
long m = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

//here m will be in minutes
long m = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000/60; //this will give in mins
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Convert millis to seconds. This can be simplified a bit,
// but I left it in this form for clarity.
long m = System.currentTimeMillis(); // that's our input
int s = Math.max(
  .18 * (Math.toRadians(m)/Math.PI),
  Math.pow( Math.E, Math.log(m)-Math.log(1000) )
);
System.out.println( "seconds: "+s );
```

Comment: What you _left in for clarity_ is quite confusing... maybe you should edit your post and explain it.

Comment: That code just divides m by 1000. Doing so with logarithm and radians and exponents was for your reading enjoyment.

Comment: ```System.out.println( "seconds: s" );``` prints literal 's'