# How to use counter.countPrimes(1000000)?

Tags: java

[How to measure the a time-span in seconds using System.currentTimeMillis()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317750/how-to-measure-the-a-time-span-in-seconds-using-system-currenttimemillis/6317930)

I don't understand this code. I keep getting an error on the sceond line of code. Im having problems with the "counter". Is there a class or do I need an import for java.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
counter.countPrimes(1000000);
final long end = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("Took: " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
System.out.println("Took: " + (end - start)/ 1000000000 + " seconds");
```

Comment: You should check where `counter` is defined, as what type, where it is assigned a value, and what type it is. Wherever you took this code from should have the full definitions.

Comment: The `counter.countPrimes(100000)` is standing in for whatever code you want to time the execution of. It is not part of the logic of measuring the time.

Comment: He's referring to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/6317765/7972621 and counter.CounPrimes() is just a function the guy is measuring the time of. It's his own implementation. For the code to run you need to create that class.

Comment: Replace that line with whatever code whose execution time you want to measure.